# Pass files with the same prefix into an array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, file

There are files in a directory that partly start the same way:

- C001_200129.pdf
- C001_29292.pdf
- C001_ABCDF.pdf
- C041_29292.pdf
- C041_110101.pdf
- P121_AAAA.pdf
- P121_CCCC.pdf
- P121_DDDD.pdf
- P121_AKAKA.pdf

The files with the same prefix (which I do not know beforehand), I only know that the first 4 characters are the same, are to be merged.

```
pdftk.exe $a*.pdf CAT OUTPUT \Merged\$a-merged.pdf
```

How do I loop through to find all the files that have the same prefix and then pass them into the $a variable and merge them and then go directly to the next set of files that I can merge.

The goal here should be

- C001_Merged.pdf
- C041_Merged.pdf
- P121_Merged.pdf

to be able to create

Comment: You can group the files using something like `| Group-Object { $_.BaseName -replace '_.+' }` then loop over each group and pass the group of files as argument to your executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the basic steps in a comment; let me flesh them out:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |                 # Get all input files.
  Group-Object { ($_.Name -split '_')[0] } |  # Group them by shared prefix.
  ForEach-Object { # Process each group.
    pdftk.exe $_.Group.FullName CAT OUTPUT \Merged\$($_.Name)_merged.pdf
  }
```

- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) is used to group all `*.pdf` files in the current directory (add a `-LiteralPath` argument to target a different dir.) by their shared prefix (the start of the name up to, but not including `_`).
- The `.Name` property of each resulting [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo) instance contains that shared prefix, and the `.Group` property contains all file-info objects that make up the group.
- `$_.Group.FullName` uses [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to get the full paths (`.FullName`) of all file-info objects in the group; passing the resulting array of file paths to an external program such as `pdftk.exe` results in the paths getting passed as *individual arguments*.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @KaiKraft; my pleasure.